# Publish code coverage result failed in azuredevops pipeline

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a .netcode test command and a publish code coverage results task in my pipeline.

config as below:

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Test Public API Project '
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/DWP.CDA.API.Test.csproj'
    arguments: '--output publish_output --configuration $(BuildConfiguration) /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura /p:Threshold=99 /p:ThresholdStat=total /p:CoverletOutput=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResults\Coverage\ --collect "Code coverage"'

steps:
- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  displayName: 'Publish code coverage'
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
    summaryFileLocation: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/TestResults/Coverage/*cobertura.xml'
    reportDirectory: '($(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Src/TestResults/Coverage'
```

But it seems that the publish results doed not take effect,such messages will show

```
[warning]No code coverage results were found to publish.
```

Comment: I think you can set `system.debug= true` to get more detailed log about this error and share it here. This can help others investigate further.

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: Sorry for the later reply,as I have some other urgent work to do.I pended this issue and disable this step in the pipeline.I will try to solve this issue later and share progress here.

Answer (score 6):

Did you install and run the ReportGenerator tool as well to get code coverage report in the proper format? Your warning looks like the build task isn't finding the xml file to publish in the folder that you're looking in.

I've used the following yaml in the past to run and publish code coverage results. You will need to change it to find your projects, but otherwise it should work.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Install ReportGenerator'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: tool
    arguments: 'install --global dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Run unit tests - $(buildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    arguments: '--no-build --configuration $(buildConfiguration) /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura /p:CoverletOutput=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/TestResults/Coverage/'
    publishTestResults: true
    projects: '**/*.Tests.csproj'

- script: |
    reportgenerator -reports:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/**/coverage.cobertura.xml -targetdir:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/CodeCoverage -reporttypes:HtmlInline_AzurePipelines
  displayName: 'Create code coverage report'

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  displayName: 'Publish code coverage report'
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: 'cobertura'
    summaryFileLocation: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/**/coverage.cobertura.xml'
```

Comment: I‘m trying to use the script you listed to create report but failed.errors as below:
    2020-02-19T04:16:13: Working directory: D:\a\1\s
2020-02-19T04:16:13: The report file 'D:\a\1\s/TestResults/Coverage/coverage.cobertura.xml' is invalid. File does not exist (Full path: 'D:\a\1\s\TestResults\Coverage\coverage.cobertura.xml').
2020-02-19T04:16:13: No report files specified.

Comment: is there something to use for angular code coverage? this is incompatible on my case

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as SapuSevn commented, it should be Agent.TempDirectory.

```
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'dotnet test'
      inputs:
        command: 'test'
        arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" -- DataCollectionRunSettings.DataCollectors.DataCollector.Configuration.Format=cobertura'
        publishTestResults: true
        projects: 'tests/Frontends/GloboTicket.Web.Tests' # update with your test project directory

    - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
      displayName: 'Publish code coverage report'
      inputs:
        codeCoverageTool: 'Cobertura'
        #summaryFileLocation: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/coverage.cobertura.xml' ## This is not working. What you need is the following.
        summaryFileLocation: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)/**/coverage.cobertura.xml'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, take a look at the output

```
Attachments:
```

My pipeline was putting the reports into a temp folder

Also my test project was missing a Nuget `coverlet.msbuild`

Comment: For those having the same problem: Use `$(Agent.TempDirectory)` instead of`$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` when specifying `summaryFileLocation`.